# ScrollView inside ViewPager- How to scroll Parent Layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have ViewPager:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white_color">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/includeLayout"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_main_user_pic" />

   <!-- <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_below="@+id/includeLayout">

            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_180sdp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rr"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
                    android:background="#000000">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_bg"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
                        android:alpha="0.6"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/car_img" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_name"
                        style="@style/Textview_red_11sp_bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_100sdp"
                        android:text="@string/deafult_user_name"
                        android:textColor="@color/white_color" />


                    <Button
                        style="@style/ButtonBackground"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:minHeight="0dp"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:text="@string/partecipate" />


                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_90sdp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_18sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_18sdp"
                            android:src="@mipmap/web" />

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/Textview_darkgray_11sp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:text="@string/public_text" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_18sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_18sdp"
                            android:src="@mipmap/approved" />

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/Textview_darkgray_11sp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:text="@string/approved"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_18sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_18sdp"
                            android:src="@mipmap/shareimage" />

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/Textview_darkgray_11sp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:text="@string/share" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/user_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_70sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_70sdp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/profile_default"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/gray_background_color"
                    app:civ_border_overlay="true"
                    app:civ_border_width="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:layout_anchor="@+id/img_bg"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom" />


            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:background="@color/gray_background_color" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_host"
                style="@style/Tablayout_style" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        </LinearLayout>
   <!-- </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <include layout="@layout/bottom_menu_layout" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <!--</LinearLayout>-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here my viewpager fragment layout:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@color/white_color"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp">

            <!--<include
                layout="@layout/community_fragment_event_moreinfo"></include>-->


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_cal_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/timesmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_date"
                    style="@style/Textview_darkgray_11sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_cal_icon"
                    android:text="31 November - 02 December" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_date_details"
                    style="@style/Textview_gray_11sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_date"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_cal_icon"
                    android:text="@string/from_december_to_december" />


            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_location_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/location" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_circuit"
                    style="@style/Textview_darkgray_11sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_location_icon"
                    android:text="@string/sepang_international_circuit" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_circuit_details"
                    style="@style/Textview_gray_11sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_circuit"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_location_icon"
                    android:text="@string/sepang_circuit_details" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_group_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/group_gray" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_group"
                    style="@style/Textview_darkgray_11sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_group_icon"
                    android:text="@string/pilots" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_pilots_count"
                    style="@style/Textview_red_11sp_bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_group"
                    android:text="231" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_dets"
                    style="@style/Textview_darkgray_11sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_pilots_count"
                    android:text="@string/dets" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_friends"
                    style="@style/Textview_darkgray_11sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_dets"
                    android:text="@string/friends_dets" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_friends_count"
                    style="@style/Textview_red_11sp_bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_friends"
                    android:text="4" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_friends_out_of"
                    style="@style/Textview_darkgray_11sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_friends_count"
                    android:text="/231" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_group"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_group_icon" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_organized_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/organized" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_organized"
                    style="@style/Textview_darkgray_11sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_organized_icon"
                    android:text="@string/organized_by" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_car_name"
                    style="@style/Textview_red_11sp_bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_organized"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_organized_icon"
                    android:text="@string/lambnorghini" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_club_name"
                    style="@style/Textview_gray_11sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_car_name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_organized_icon"
                    android:text="@string/officials_valentino_rossis_club" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rr_dollor_amt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_dollor_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/price" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/Textview_darkgray_11sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_dollor_icon"
                    android:text="@string/dollor_amt" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:background="@color/gray_background_color" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/Textview_darkgray_11sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:text="@string/details" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/Textview_gray_11sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />

        <!--    <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/add_post_info_ll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:background="@color/gray_background_color"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/user_profile_img"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/profile_default" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/post_edittext"
                    style="@style/Textview_gray_11sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:gravity="top|left"
                    android:hint="@string/whats_happening_right"
                    android:lines="3" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/add_post_ll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/add_post_info_ll"
                android:background="@color/white_color"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/flag_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/flag" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/car_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flag_icon"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/car" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/trophy_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/car_icon"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/trophy" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/timer_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/trophy_icon"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/timer" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/sun_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/timer_icon"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/sun" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/gallery_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sun_icon"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/gallery" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/smiley_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gallery_icon"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/amiley" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/post_tv"
                    style="@style/Textview_white_11sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_back"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_3sdp"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
                    android:text="@string/post" />

            </RelativeLayout>-->


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[![][1]][1]

I want to scroll header as well when viewpager content scrolls.I tried using Nested ScrollView on both screens but didn't get any success.Can anyone help me solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: By header did you mean the ImageView?

Comment: yes I means imageview  @AjilO.